# Как облегчить сервисы android?

Tags: android, java

Прошу прощение, если вопрос ламерский. Я разработал приложение под android, в котором использую сервис. Все бы хорошо, но сервис занимает 28 мб, в то время как само приложение 3 мб. Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего это может быть? Как можно решить данную проблему?

http://pastebin.com/3q09HUbg //  Не пинайте за таймеры, пожалуйста, пока ничего лучше не придумал

Comment: на перекрестке 5 дорог надо зарыть куриный скелет в ночь с пятницы на субботу в полную луну

Comment: хотя нет, че я так, удали 100 строк - станет в 2 раза легче ему

Comment: @Gorets, с чего такой негатив к ТС? 

@Welgum, выложите, пожалуйста, код сервиса. Пользуйтесь сервисом pastebin.

Comment: @SuperCreeper ничего личного, ты тоже мог бы оказаться на его месте.